# How to extract a parameter from a hash in a URL [React Native]

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, url

How would I go about extracting a "parameter" or "argument" from a hash in a url?
`https://example.com/blahblahblah#key=value&scope`
An API is giving me a weird token that is in a long URL and I need to get it from the hash, but it is in this weird format
React Native does not support the URLsearchparams functions in JavaScript

I get `key=value&scope` but I need `value`

Comment: `new URLSearchParams(new URL(url).hash.replace(/^#/, '')).get('key')`

Comment: Just a note on the duplicate... yes the linked post is about actual query string but since OP's hash is in the same format (`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`), the same answers apply

Comment: Probably should have mentioned this is react native, URLSearchParams doesn't work